Excel paste from PowerPoint as text not number
I've copied numeric values from a PowerPoint presentation into a column in excel
However, when I try to convert to numeric it just remains as text.
I've tried

Data > Text to Column
Paste special > Multiply
and nothing works it just remains as text

Has anyone come across this and found a solution?
Thanks in advance
Julie

Have you tried creating a temporary column that converts the text to a number? For example, if the numbers are in column A and the temporary column is column B, you would enter as the formula for column b:
=VALUE(a1)

You would need to copy this formula down to all rows and use it instead of column A for calculations.

Hi, I did try that, it didn't change the formating to numeric nor did it error. What tried in the end was copying the data into Notes then copying back into excel, which showed "?" Character. Which i then deleted in all cells. A dirty workaround, would be great to be able to strip any unprintable characters at the time of initially pasting.

Glad you were able to identify the problem. Maybe someone knows a simple way to strip unprintable characters when pasting text. It's even more frustrating when you can't even see them.
